# SQL SELECT query with JOIN, SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 5 tables in a MS Access databse: tblMember, tblPoint, tblRace, tblRaceType and tblResult. (All of which have primary keys.)
tblPoint contains (RaceTypeID, Position, Points) fields.

What I want to do is look at all the races that the members participated in, see what position they came (stored in tblResult) and see if those positions score points (as defined in tblPoint). I then want to add up all the points for each member and show these, along with the member name in my query...

Is this possible? I came up with my best shot at this SQL query below:

```
SELECT Sum(tblPoint.Points) AS SumOfPoints, Count(tblRace.RaceID) AS CountOfRaceID,     
tblMember.MemberName, tblPoint.Points
FROM ((tblRaceType INNER JOIN tblPoint ON tblRaceType.RaceTypeID = tblPoint.RaceTypeID)    
INNER JOIN tblRace ON tblRaceType.RaceTypeID = tblRace.RaceTypeID) INNER JOIN   
(tblMember INNER JOIN tblResult ON tblMember.MemberID = tblResult.MemberID) ON    
tblRace.RaceID = tblResult.RaceID
GROUP BY tblMember.MemberName, tblPoint.Points
ORDER BY tblPoint.Points DESC;
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction at all?

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve way too much with sql...Atleast I can say that you have done a good job with your query so far...but the problem here is you are trying to yield a result set which to me looks impossible...to me this problem/issue must be addressed in your business logic of you application...where you can construct the desired format with multiple queries results...

Comment: Apologies, it is not satisfactory because at the moment for someone who has entered 1 race and come first in that same race, it returns the same memberName multiple times, each time assigning points for coming first, second, third etc.

I did wonder if I was trying to do too much!

Comment: @LNB: It's actually quite possible to do this in plain SQL without any special trickery. You are actually very close with your solution, the problem is that you grouped by Points (see my answer). Also, there is no link between result and points, thats why you get all points for every placement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this

```
GROUP BY tblMember.MemberName, tblPoint.Points
ORDER BY tblPoint.Points DESC;
```

should probably be more like this:

```
GROUP BY tblMember.MemberName
ORDER BY Sum(tblPoint.Points) DESC;
```

Also, remove `tblPoint.Points` at the end of your select. This is just a single point value, you want the sum.

Grouping by points means that you'll get one row per member and point value they scored - probably not what you intended.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! It works perfectly thanks to your excellent guidance. :)